# How do I set syntax highlighting in Notepad++ for a PHP file outputting JS?

Tags: javascript, php, notepad++, syntax-highlighting

PHP is most commonly used to echo out HTML, but for this project I'm using PHP to echo out JavaScript.

How can I set syntax highlighting in Notepad++ to assume that anything outside of PHP tags is JS?

For example, in:

```
function(){
    var message='<?php echo 'value'; ?>';
}
```

I want the surrounding `function` and various marks to be highlighted like JS, not like HTML.

(I know anything inside of `echo` statements won't be highlighted as JS, so I'm not worried about that. Just JavaScript outside of the PHP tags)

Answer (score 0):

I should probably feel ashamed for this answer, but it's such a quick shortcut I'm kinda proud of it.

```
<?php echo '//'; ?><script>
function(){
    var message='<?php echo 'value'; ?>';
}
<?php echo '//'; ?></script>
```

I'd still love an actual answer to this question as I've had a hard time figuring it out, but this fools Notepad++ into highlighting the JavaScript correctly and the `<script>` tags get commented out, so it works on both fronts for me.